# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Никак не соображу: сложносочиненное или сложноподчиненное это предложение: "Я люблю свою подругу(,) и сейчас, когда она уехала, мне ее очень не хватает". Нужна ли запятая перед "и"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот предложение с союзной сочинительной и подчинительной связью. Запятая нужна.